# Browser Tab and Tab name have inconsistent capitalization

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

When renaming the SO tab, it is converted into lower case characters instantly when leaving the text field.
The browser tab however keeps the used capitalization.

[image]

So either caps should be allowed in the SO tab name or the browser tabname should have the same format.

Comment: Solution: open more tabs, only have favicons show (if that). :)

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in build `#3919` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3024` (stackoverflow.com).